# How do i shift the values in a column of a data frame either up or down?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write some code that effectively shifts the values in the first column of a dataframe either up or down. The conditions for it moving up or down are as follows:

1) If the difference between the value directly below the selected element in the data frame 'playerlist' and the value of the selected element is less than OR equal to the difference between the value directly above the selected element in the data frame and the value of the selected element then the data in the first column shift up (i.e. the playerlist[1, 1] becomes playerlist[2, 1], playerlist[2, 1] becomes playlist[3, 1] etc.).

2) If the converse is true, (i.e. the difference between the value directly below the selected element in the data frame 'playerlist' and the value of the selected element is (only) more than the difference between the value directly above the selected element in the data frame and the value of the selected element) then the data shifts down (i.e. the playerlist[3, 1] becomes playerlist[2, 1], playerlist[2, 1] becomes playlist[1, 1] etc.).

3) If neither the above value or the below value of the selected element's value are less than the selected value, then nothing happens.

NB:

*number_of_players is an external input, in the below example it is running with value 7 (i.e. this means that playerlist contains 7 rows.

**Take x to be the row of the selected data (i.e. so the selected data is always playerlist[x, 1]).

```
dicear <- function(x){ #x is the player playing the card
    y <- x-1
    z <- x+1
    if(x <- 1){
        y <- number_of_players
    }
    if(x <- number_of_players){
        z <- 1
    }
    if(playerlist[x, 1]>playerlist[z, 1] & (playerlist[x, 1]-playerlist[z, 1]) >= (playerlist[x, 1] - playerlist[y, 1])){
        for(i in 1:nrow(playerlist)){
        dummy <- i+1
        if(i <- nrow(playerlist)){
            dummy <- 1
            }
        else{
            dummy <- i+1
            }
        playerlist[i, 1] <<- playerlist[dummy, 1]
    }
    }
    else {
        if(playerlist[x, 1]>playerlist[y, 1] & (playerlist[x, 1]-playerlist[y, 1]>(playerlist[x, 1]-playerlist[z, 1]))){
            for(i in 1:nrow(playerlist)){
            dummy <- i-1
            if(i <- 1){
                dummy <- nrow(playerlist)
            }
            else{
                dummy <- i-1
                }
            playerlist[i, 1] <<- playerlist[dummy, 1]   
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following completely, but it seems like you're trying to create some kind of sorting algorithm based on the differences between the items above and below some target. Is that correct?

Comment: Additionally, wouldn't your algorithm fail on both the first and last items of your data frame?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

To help clarify the question that you have, I am providing some guidelines to make this problem easier for me to approach. Shifting data around in a vector is simpler to consider than moving data in columns of a data frames.  Data frames columns can be vectorized (saved as vectors).  Your question asks to evaluate the differences between the previous value `(i-1)`, and the following value `(i+1)` where `i` is the value being evaluated.  As given, this excludes the first and final values.  The first value has no previous value and the final value has no next value to perform the difference calculation.  I will focus on a single position in a given vector.

Given the vector, `z <- c(1, 2, 8, 4, 5)` lets go through the procedure given by your guidelines.  For simplicity, calculate the absolute value of the differences evaluating `z[2]`.

```
> abs(z[1] - z[2])
[1] 1
> abs(z[2] - z[3])
[1] 6
```

The `abs(z[2] - z[3]) > abs(z[1] -z[2])` and the value `z[2]` shifts down to modify the vector to be 'z <- c(1,8,2,4,5)`.

Repeating the procedure on `z[2]`, which is now 8, gives the following result: `z <- c(1,2,8,4,5)` which is the original vector.  So instead let's test `z[3]`, which is 2: `z <- c(1,2,8,4,5)`.  Again back to the original vector.  My thinking may be flawed.  Please provide examples in the comments if I have made a mistake.

That considered, the following may be useful.

```
z <- c(1,2,8,4,5)
for(i in 1:5) print(c(z[i], z[-i]))
```

If all you want to do is shift a particular value around, the simple `for` loop given above will `print()` those sequences where `i` is the iteration variable from one through 5 (`1:5`).  As `i` advances, the resulting vector shifts the place value at `z[i]` to the first position (i.e `z[1] <- z[i]`).  None of the values are lost.

```
> for(i in 1:5) print(c(z[i], z[-i]))
[1] 1 2 8 4 5
[1] 2 1 8 4 5
[1] 8 1 2 4 5
[1] 4 1 2 8 5
[1] 5 1 2 8 4
```

You can also calculate the differences in the vector using `diff()`.

```
> diff(z)
[1]  1  6 -4  1
> abs(diff(z))
[1] 1 6 4 1
```

The values calculated by `diff()` are essentially the same values you wish to evaluate where the first value given by `diff()` is the difference between `z[1]` and `z[2]`; the second is the difference between `z[2]` and `z[3]`, and so on.  You could perform comparisons using difference values from `diff()`.

```
> diffs <- diff(z)
> diffs[1] > diffs[2] | diffs[2] <= diffs[3]
[1] FALSE
> diffs[2] > diffs[3] | diffs[3] <= diffs[4]
[1] TRUE
```

Keep in mind that `z` has 5 elements whereas `diffs` has only 4 elements.

You may provide some details about your questions such as an example of `playerlist` and output for what changes you propose to see in the data frame.

Another option that may or may not be helpful is the `sort()` function.  When I first read your question I thought maybe you were trying to sequentially sort your data one at a time, for example to change a a player's ranking according to a turn of a game.  You may arrange your data from smallest to largest using `sort()`.

```
> sort(z)
[1] 1 2 4 5 8
```

There is an interesting principle here to explore.